# JavaScript, async/await and behaviour of code

Tags: javascript, async-await

Initially, I had a code like this:

```
handleOnSelectFile = event => {
    // a lot of code using 'event', props, etc.

    SomeFunction.parse(someVar, {complete: async results => {
        // more code
        this.setState({ someExampleState: true})});
    }
});
}
```

Now I have to use a function with async/await, so the function becomes like:

```
handleOnSelectFile = async event => {
// a lot of code using 'event', props, etc.

SomeFunction.parse(someVar, {complete: async results => {
    // more code
    await getAll(type);// <--- THIS IS NEW
    this.setState({ someExampleState: true})});
  }
});
}
```

My question is, on using `async` on the whole `handleOnSelectFile` parameter, is there a possibility of having unexpected behaviour with the code inside? The only reason of using `async/await` is for the `getAll` function in the end of my code.

Comment: `handleOnFileSelect` now returns a promise rather than a value, so there is certainly the possibility of behavior changing.  It's impossible to give a helpful answer without more context of the actual code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there will not be any unsuspected behavior because using async in the parent function without using await within the block scope is the same as writing a regular function but the value it returns will be a promise. TLDR You only need the async/await keywords in the child function or wherever function blocks the promise is in.